# How to assign more than one value to variable

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have 211 number values which I need to assign to variable. How to manage this?

For example:

```
declare 
id_v number := 1.3.5.6,55,6666,44545;
```

Just to say those values can be selected from table.

Thanks

Comment: where do these numbers come from, and how often does the list change?  Depending on their source and use, it is highly likely that trying to put them in a single comma-delimited variable may not be the best way of handling them.  This smells like yet another x-y question.  https://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 0):

That can't be a scalar (`number`) datatype variable. Either declare your own type, or use what Oracle provides: `sys.odcinumberlist`. For example:

```
SQL> declare
  2    id_v sys.odcinumberlist := sys.odcinumberlist(1, 3, 5, 66, 7777);
  3  begin
  4    for cur_r in (select column_value from table(id_v)) loop
  5      dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.column_value);
  6    end loop;
  7  end;
  8  /
1
3
5
66
7777

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

Or, as you said that values can be fetched from a table:

```
SQL> declare
  2    id_v sys.odcinumberlist;
  3  begin
  4    select empno
  5      bulk collect into id_v
  6      from emp
  7      where deptno = 20;
  8
  9    for cur_r in (select column_value from table(id_v)) loop
 10      dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.column_value);
 11    end loop;
 12  end;
 13  /
7566
7788
7902
7369
7876

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```